# Delphi database created and modified using DBNavigation

Tags: mysql, delphi, datetime, delphi-7, delphi-2010

Guys am looking how can i optimise my `DBNavigation` to automatically insert or update date and time in database col when i make changes in `DBGrid`.

In database i has `ID, Name, Description, Created<datetime>, Modified<datetime>`

Now when i change some col in dbgrid and click to save (post edit) i want to insert  or update date and time when is created or modified!

I serach on google about this but i dont found.

Am new in delphi...

Anyone can give me example or link where i can read more about that!

Comment: It has nothing with DBNavigator or any other GUI components. IT belongs to data access leyer.  Solution 1: use `TDataset.BeforePost` event to set the values of those fields. Solution 2: use MySQL triggers to do it, without even touching Delphi code.

Comment: see https://habrahabr.ru/post/146717/‎ and https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Триггер_(базы_данных)

Comment: I dont understand `Rusian` language

Comment: then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger / logging should be done by the database itself not by php/Delphi or any other application

Comment: something like that (of course updating where needed to MySQL syntax): http://pastebin.ca/3707988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the dataset which is connected to the grid.

In the IDE, click on the dataset and go to the Object Inspector Events tab.

Find the `BeforePost` event, double click in it and enter code like this

```
if MyDataSet.State = dsInsert then  //  a new record is being added
  MyDataSet.FieldByName('Created').AsDateTime := Now;
else
  //  modifying an existing record
  MyDataSet.FieldByName('Modified').AsDateTime := Now;
```

As noted in a comment, you can populate/update these fields using triggers on the server,  but then you have to refresh the data in your Delphi dataset to receive the values in these fields, which is perhaps a bit advanced for where you are at the moment.

Comment: Also since he has more experience with MySQL and PHP than in Delphi - the more code he would program in MySQL - the less he would have to do (and to maintain in future) in Delphi. He would better use his skills by programming more in MySQL and less in Delphi

Comment: Depending of the db-access library he uses, shouldn't be re-reading posted record automatic via `TDataSet.ReSync` ?